# Managing a stopwatch mobile app

Tags: javascript, optimization, design-patterns, timer

I'm using the following pattern in my mobile app. The code snippet below manages a stopwatch.

Is there a way to simplify the code for better readability and probably getting away from needing to use `MyApp.stopwatch.` inside it? Somehow in some cases using `this` instead works, and in some it doesn't.

And what about getting rid of using repeating `var settings = MyApp.stopwatch.settings`?

```
(function (MyApp, $, undefined) {

    // Using strict mode to throw exceptions for 'unsafe' actions and coding patterns
    'use strict';

    // Initializes app
    function init() {
        MyApp.stopwatch.init('startStopwatch', 'pauseStopwatch', 'resetStopwatch');
    }

    // Manages the stopwatch
    MyApp.stopwatch = {

        init: function (startButton, pauseButton, resetButton) {
            document.getElementById(startButton).addEventListener('click', MyApp.stopwatch.startTimer, false);
            document.getElementById(pauseButton).addEventListener('click', MyApp.stopwatch.pauseTimer, false);
            document.getElementById(resetButton).addEventListener('click', MyApp.stopwatch.resetTimer, false);

            MyApp.stopwatch.displayTimer();
        },

        settings: {
            timerId: -1,
            interval: 100,
            millis: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            minutes: 0
        },

        displayTimer: function () {
            // ARE THESE REPEATING DECLARATIONS REALLY NEEDED?
            var settings            = MyApp.stopwatch.settings,
                millis              = Math.round(settings.millis / 100).toFixed(0),
                seconds             = settings.seconds,
                minutes             = settings.minutes;

            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds             = '0' + seconds;
            }
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes             = '0' + minutes;
            }
            document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + millis;
        },

        updateTimer: function () {
            // ARE THESE REPEATING DECLARATIONS REALLY NEEDED?
            var settings            = MyApp.stopwatch.settings;
            settings.millis         += settings.interval;
            if (settings.millis >= 1000) {
                settings.millis     = 0;
                settings.seconds    += 1;
            }
            if (settings.seconds >= 60) {
                settings.millis     = 0;
                settings.seconds    = 0;
                settings.minutes    += 1;
            }
            MyApp.stopwatch.displayTimer();
        },

        pauseTimer: function () {
            // ARE THESE REPEATING DECLARATIONS REALLY NEEDED?
            var settings    = MyApp.stopwatch.settings;
            window.clearInterval(settings.timerId);
            settings.timerId = -1;
        },

        startTimer: function () {
            // ARE THESE REPEATING DECLARATIONS REALLY NEEDED?
            var settings    = MyApp.stopwatch.settings;
            if (settings.timerId === -1) {
                settings.timerId = window.setInterval(MyApp.stopwatch.updateTimer, settings.interval);
            }
        },

        resetTimer: function () {
            // ARE THESE REPEATING DECLARATIONS REALLY NEEDED?
            var settings    = MyApp.stopwatch.settings;
            MyApp.stopwatch.pauseTimer();
            settings.millis = 0;
            settings.seconds = 0;
            settings.minutes = 0;
            MyApp.stopwatch.displayTimer();
        }

    };

    // PhoneGap, jQuery & device is ready now -> initialize
    $(document).on('deviceready', init);

}(window.MyApp = window.MyApp || {}, jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with (untested):

I got rid of your settings-stuff, introduced a variable `self` so there's no interference with `this`, moved your initialization code to the only place it is (and can ever be) called from, extracted a method for padding and event handler registration and fixed your updateTimer so it works for values > 1000 (it's not fit for negative values, though). I hope you like it...

```
(function (MyApp, $, undefined) {
    // Using strict mode to throw exceptions for 'unsafe' actions and coding patterns
    'use strict';

    function addClickHandlerToButton(buttonId, handler) {
        document.getElementById(buttonId).addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    }

    function padLeft(number) {
        number = +number;
        return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(number);
    }

    // Manages the stopwatch
    var stopwatch = (function(){
        var minutes = 0,
            seconds = 0,
            millis = 0,
            interval = 100,
            timerId = -1,
        displayTimer = function () {
            document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML =
                padLeft(minutes) + ':' +
                padLeft(seconds) + ':' +
                Math.floor(millis);
        },

        updateTimer = function () {
            millis += interval;
            if (millis >= 1000) {
                seconds += millis / 1000;
                millis %= 1000;
            }
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                minutes += seconds / 60;
                seconds %= 60;
            }
            displayTimer();
        },

        pauseTimer = function () {
            window.clearInterval(timerId);
            timerId = -1;
        },

        startTimer = function () {
            if (timerId === -1) {
                timerId = window.setInterval(updateTimer, interval);
            }
        },

        resetTimer = function () {
            pauseTimer();
            millis = 0;
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            displayTimer();
        };

        return function (startButton, pauseButton, resetButton) {
            addClickHandlerToButton(startButton, startTimer)
            addClickHandlerToButton(pauseButton, pauseTimer)
            addClickHandlerToButton(resetButton, stopTimer)
            displayTimer();
        };
    })();

    // PhoneGap, jQuery & device is ready now -> initialize
    $(document).on('deviceready', function() {
        stopwatch('startStopwatch', 'pauseStopwatch', 'resetStopwatch');
    });

}(window.MyApp = window.MyApp || {}, jQuery));
```

**EDIT 1+2:** updated the code to integrate suggestions from the comments by the OP and fix errors.

Comment: Looks good. Especially like the handler function. Never seen `self.self = self;` being used? Is it a good practice? And doesn't `init` and `displayTimer` have a different scope? So when you assign `MyApp.stopwatch.self = MyApp.stopwatch` can you really just call `self.millis`? Because if you can access MyApp.stopwatch with `self` inside any of those functions, why can't you then just call `displayTimer()` instead of `self.displayTimer`, or `millis` instead of `self.millis`

Comment: You are right, my changes weren't fully thought through and included redundancies (and a copy paste error, I used the same button for all 3 event handler registrations). Please have another look. I also moved `self` - it's a neat trick, although in this version, it isn't really needed anymore.

Comment: My questions on last comment were kind of rhetorical. The code won't still work because those functions have different scope and therefore you just can't call `stopTimer` or `millis` inside them. But yeah, I'll implement that handler-function.

Comment: Hmm... I really need a testbed :-) - just give them scope by making MyApp.stopwatch a function. I'll do another rewrite!

Comment: Although you've changed the pattern, i'll accept this as an answer. Good effort. Ty!